# How come China won't allow unfettered access to ambassadors when tourists can freely go to Xinjiang on their own?

Tags: international-relations, international

https://www.scmp.com/news/china/diplomacy/article/3133267/un-members-call-immediate-meaningful-and-unfettered-access

> ‘If you have nothing to hide, why do you not finally grant unimpeded
> access?’ one ambassador asks

How come China won't allow unfettered access to ambassadors when tourists can freely go to Xinjiang on their own? I don't understand China's political motivations to resist this effort by Western countries to open up China for investigation. On one hand, anyone can go to Xinjiang to travel, on the other hand, China won't allow investigators to freely walk around.

Comment: I 'm guessing that the typical tourist doesn't have "unimpeded access"

Comment: Except tourists can't freely visit everywhere in Xinjiang... how could they otherwise hide the concentration camps?

Comment: Even in less extreme places: [When trying to access Imam Musa Kazim mosque, reporters were assaulted by 30 men in plain clothes, who hit the journalists in the face](https://twitter.com/Telegraph/status/1404116544825798661?s=20)

Comment: Do you have any reliable source?